# JSON.getString doesn't return null

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have a response coming back from a server and I am expecting a String value, so I wrote this for parsing it

```
public String getMessageFromServer(JSONObject response) {
    String msg = response.getString("message");
    return msg;
}
```

then, when I use this in my code and get a `null` value from the server, the function doesn't return `null`, it returns `"null"` instead.

I have seen [this bug report](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/issues/5), but I don't see a solution.

**EDIT:**

I have a small hack to solve this but it's ugly and I'm looking for a better solution:

```
public String getMessageFromServer(JSONObject response) {
    Object msg = response.get("message");
    if(msg == null) {
         return null;
    }
    return (String) msg;
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

after years, going back to this question, I see that I was not entirely wrong here and that `JSONObject` has a built in method for this.

The way to get an optional value from a `JSONObject` is with using [this method](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString-java.lang.String-) `JSONObject.optString("message", DEF_VALUE);`

Comment: it is ok, but it's an ugly hack and I dislike it

Comment: Why is that ugly or a hack? You are just doing it well

Comment: it's ugly because, I expect a String value (that can be `null`) but have to deal with type casting.

Comment: Would checking for "null", in the first example, be less ugly?

Comment: it'll be time consuming, testing for the `null` value takes almost no time, testing for value of `String` takes a long time.

Comment: @thepoosh - you are optimizing prematurely.  It is highly unlikely that the difference between `==` and `String.equals` will be significant.

Comment: @thepoosh Please note that `JSONObject.optString()` does coerce `JSONObject.NULL` to string with value `"null"` too. In other words `"null".equals(new JSONObject().put("test", JSONObject.NULL).optString("test", null))` gives `true`.

Comment: The way to get an optional value from a JSONObject is with using this method JSONObject.optString("message", DEF_VALUE);
This worked for me! Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The hack looks okay for your situation.

The other option would be to use the method `boolean isNull(String key)` and then based on the returned boolean value proceed with your option. Something like:

```
public String getMessageFromServer(JSONObject response) {
    return ((response.has("message") && !response.isNull("message"))) ? response.getString("message") : null;
}
```

But then, I don't think there's much of a difference between the your current implementation and this.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the correct method to check for a null value. But I don't agree when you say there is not much difference. The isNUll-call is cleaner and should be preferred towards relying on Object and casting.

Comment: can't you remove the `response.has("message)"` check? Whenever that key doesn't exist, `isNull` will return true, so `getString` won't be called and no exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to solve when using Kotlin class extensions:

```
fun JSONObject.optNullableString(name: String, fallback: String? = null) : String? {
    return if (this.has(name) && !this.isNull(name)) {
        this.getString(name)
    } else {
        fallback
    }
}
```

Then e.g. `name` will be null in:

```
val name : String? = JSONObject("""{"id": "foo", "name":null}""").optNullableString("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple way in Kotlin

```
fun JSONObject.getNullableString(name: String) : String? {
    if (has(name) && !isNull(name)) {
        return getString(name)
    }
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android sdk default value in optString method is annotated as @NonNull.
Just skip it and simplify to get value or null:

```
fun JSONObject.optStringOrNull(key: String, fallback: String? = null): String? {
    val obj: Any? = opt(key)
    if (obj is String) {
        return obj
    } else if (obj != null) {
        return obj.toString()
    }
    return fallback
}
```